# How change the detailView in a Master-Detail application for iPad

Tags: xcode, ipad, master-detail

I have make a simply Master-Detail application for iPad where I've a UITableView in the MasterViewController.m

Now When I use the didSelectRowAtIndexPath how I can change the DetailView with my DettaglioView.m (and nib)?

I've start with the Xcode template but It push in the MasterViewController.m a view in the yours NavigationController. Well I need to select the cell and change the detailView

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    //è la classe che usa per visualizzare il dettaglio
    //UIViewController <SubstitutableDetailViewController> *detailViewController = nil;


    if (!self.detailViewController) {
        self.detailViewController = [[[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    }

    DettaglioView *newDetailViewController = [[DettaglioView alloc] initWithNibName:@"DettaglioView" bundle:nil];
    //detailViewController = newDetailViewController;


    //[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

How Can I intercept the DetailView to change with my DettaglioView?

Comment: I'll try now to use "SubstitutableDetailViewController"

Answer (score 0):

You're wanting to replace whatever is in the detail?  Is that what you're asking?  Can you just [self.navigationController popToRootViewController:detailViewController animated: NO]?

Comment: Yes I waiting to replace the detail view whit my class instance. Maybe, I thinking that the instance view is back of my detail view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the another ViewController to appear in place of the table, try this :

```
//shows lvc in master
yourNewViewController *yvc = [[yourNewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LyourNewViewControllerNibNameHere" bundle:nil];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:yvc animated:YES];
```